# How to get installed wallets on android browser? window.cardano is undefined

Tags: mobile-wallet

we have implemented an app that reads the wallets via window.cardano in the browser.
When we run this app in the browser on an Android device, the window.cardano object is undefined.
How can we access the wallets and API in a browser on an Android device? Is there a way?
Greetings
Waldemar

Comment: What browser do you use on mobile? And what wallet did you install in that browser?

Comment: hi, i'm using chrome and firefox and i've installed nami, gerowallet and yoroi wallets. thanks

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to install extensions on Chrome for Android.. If you managed to install any of these wallets in your phone's Chrome/Firefox browser, then the connection should work the same way as on the PC.